# 1 section title for multiple pages pdfpages

Tags: sectioning, pdfpages, appendix

I have tried to add a section title to my multiple pages pdfpages in the appendix. 
However, my attempt was wrong, as it now creates a new section title for every page of the included (multiplepages) pdf.

What I would like to achieve is only one heading as section title for 1 included pdf, regardless of the amount of pages.

Maybe someone has an idea how to achieve that?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Anhang}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anhang}
\KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
    \setcounter{page}{2}
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} %A
\includepdf[pages=-,,scale=0.75,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}\section{Testsektion}]{KoreanWeeklyNews.pdf}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Reference picture: [image: Reference]

Comment: Basically I was able to find a workaround, although it does not really appear to be a pretty solution: 
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.7,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}\section{Auszug aus archivierter Website \textsc{Twitch Film}}]{KoreanWeeklyNews.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-,scale=0.7,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{KoreanWeeklyNews.pdf}